# Retrieve value from an object

Tags: php, xml, class, object

I have an object and like to retrieve the value of one or more elements from the object. Hire is one of the objects if put in a var_dump().

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#13 (2) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "chain"
  }
  ["value"]=>
  string(11) "Abba Hotels"
}
```

I get the value but i can not get to the name.

To get the value i use for example:

```
echo $row->property->value
```

My first thought was to use:

```
echo $row->property->@attributes->name
```

, but it return as a ERROR. I try to use @attributes in a variable but that gives a NULL.

At second thought i tried to use get_object_vars() and in_array() but no luck again.

Do you guys have a idea about how i can get to the value of the "name" object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the docs for [SimpleXMLElement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php):

```
$object->attributes()
```

Will give you what you need. I.e.

```
echo $object->attributes()->name;
```

Comment: Hi Jim,
Thanks for your response it did work: $object->attributes()

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a property value from somewhere. If $row is the object, then you could use this I think.

```
$row->@attritubes['name']
```

Im not fully sure but thought id give it a go helping anyawy. Let me know if it works.